# The ACF has too many significant lags, while the PACF has 3/4 significant lags. How can I choose some model from this differenced data?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

[image: Differenced Data]

This is the correlogram of differenced data.

Comment: the series looks seasonal. what's the period? do you have any reason to suppose seasonal autocorrelation?